# SQL Server: How to get physical partition number of a row?

Tags: sql-server

We all know for each row in a table, there will be a partition to store this row.

I searched the stackoverflow, and find there is a post "Get A records current partition"
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22638/get-a-records-current-partition

However I am not quite clear how to do that.

Could someone give a concrete example?

If I have a table Employee, which has a non cluster index on EmployName and cluster index on EmployID, then how to find the partition number of the index and the cluster index where the row whose EmployID is 41245 resides in?

More information:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
( 
    EmployeeID int identity(1,1) not null
    , EmployeeName varchar(200) not null
    , constraint PK_Employee_1 primary key clustered
        (
            EmployeeID
        )
    , INDEX NONCLUSTERED IX_EmployeeName ON Employee (EmployeeName)
)
```

Comment: We can provide a real-world example for your situation if you post your CREATE table statement and name of the partition function the partition scheme is based on.

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve where the *solution* you've come up with requires you to get the "physical partition number"? We might have better solutions.

Comment: I want to know if there is a possibility of deadlock of two rows when they shared same resource (index, heap, partition). For example, update row 1 and read row 2. Another session is update row 2 and read row 1.